# Gdax sandbox Websocket API not returning correct prices

Tags: python-2.7, sandbox, gdax-api

I am currently using gdax api python example as found here: https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python for learning purposes using the gdax sandbox API.

I am trying to get real time trade prices from the sandbox through wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.gdax.com using the following code:

```
import gdax, time
class myWebsocketClient(gdax.WebsocketClient):
    def on_open(self):
        self.url = "wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.gdax.com"
        self.products = ["LTC-USD"]
        self.message_count = 0
        print("Lets count the messages!")
    def on_message(self, msg):
        self.message_count += 1
        if 'price' in msg and 'type' in msg:
            print ("Message type:", msg["type"],
                   "\t@ {:.3f}".format(float(msg["price"])))
    def on_close(self):
        print("-- Goodbye! --")

wsClient = myWebsocketClient()
wsClient.start()
print(wsClient.url, wsClient.products)
while (wsClient.message_count < 500):
    print ("\nmessage_count =", "{} \n".format(wsClient.message_count))
    time.sleep(1)
wsClient.close()
```

However, the prices I am getting are almost always 10,000USD , and not the price shown on the gdax sandbox website: https://public.sandbox.gdax.com/

When using the actual gdax websocket url: wss://ws-feed.gdax.com/, the prices seem correct.

I wonder what the problem is. Do we need a different approach to get the real time feed from sandbox?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the sandbox only does btc-usd. If you run your code with BTC-USD in place of LTC-USD it will print out. other than that it works fine.